# How to identify Taproot transaction using big query?

Tags: taproot, database

From [bitcoin magazine](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/technical/bitcoin-taproot-explainer), I saw that

> When Taproot/Schnorr goes live soon, they will use the new witness version one to distinguish them from older Segregated Witness transactions.

But when I check the type of inputs/outputs after Nov 14, I only see witness_v0_scripthash, witness_v0_keyhash, scripthash, multisig, nonstandard, witness_unknown and pubkeyhash.

Should the new taproot txns be labelled as witness_v1? or is there any other way to identify them on big-query?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting your data from? witness_v0_scripthash etc isn't blockchain data, it is manipulated data from the blockchain. Sounds like wherever you are getting your data from hasn't upgraded to recognize witness_v1 etc

Comment: BigQuery is just a data warehouse, I'm assuming it isn't manipulating and presenting  blockchain data to you. Please correct me if wrong!

Comment: Yup, this is processed data from [Big Querys Crypto Bitcoin](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/introducing-six-new-cryptocurrencies-in-bigquery-public-datasets-and-how-to-analyze-them) schema. I'm very new with this, and didn't find any way to extract bitcoin blockchain data in an sql style, so that's why I was using it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clarified in the comments that you are using [BigQuery datasets](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/introducing-six-new-cryptocurrencies-in-bigquery-public-datasets-and-how-to-analyze-them) and so you are right Taproot transactions should eventually be labelled as `witness_v1_...`. Taproot only activated a couple of days ago at the time of writing so presumably the authors haven't added Taproot support yet. You can either wait for them to do so (or request they do!) or find an alternative SQL data source that has added Taproot support. If it is the latter feel free to ask a separate question on this site, I'm not familiar with any alternative SQL blockchain data sources.